# Laravel unit testing class not found error

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm trying to do unit tests with laravel but get the following error.  I've not got to testing the function.  In my editor, I see the reference to the class correctly, however phpunit can't find it.

```
 Error: Class 'GoCardlessCheck' not found
```

my test looks like this

```
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
  use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;



class GoCardlessTest extends TestCase
{
/**
 * A basic test example.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function testExample()
 {
    $acc = new GoCardlessCheck();

    $acc->CheckAccount('bob','mould','909090','57-77-90');

 }
```

}

Comment: Have imported the class `GoCardlessCheck` ?

Comment: imported the class? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue randomly occur for me, and this is what fixed it.

First, ensure that you're including a `use path\to\GoCardlessCheck` statement. If that path is in the `tests` namespace, make sure that you have

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ]
}
```

in your `composer.json` file.

If all that is there, try running `composer update`.

After doing this the error went away, and my tests ran properly again.